# SELECT ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', POLYGON(KML?)) with google Fusion Tables

Tags: select, polygon, google-fusion-tables

I've seen that with st_intersects you can call...

```
ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', circle(latlng(lat,lng),1))
```

How do you write it if you want to have a polygon instead?

```
ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', polygon(
outerBoundaryIs(
latlng(lat,lng),latlng(lat,lng)),(..next shape)
)))
```

or can we actually use kml like this in some way?

```
ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', '<MultiGeometry><Polygon>
<tessellate>1</tessellate><extrude>0</extrude>
<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
<outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
<coordinates>lats,lngs</coordinates>
</LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>')
```

Thanks!
Quince

**ANSWER(wouldn't let me post it yet):**
I figured this par out.

```
SELECT 'name' FROM 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('geometry',  
POLYGON( 
LATLNG(40.249528, -120.8435),  
LATLNG(40.258326, -121.061249),  
LATLNG(40.301765, -121.007911),  
LATLNG(40.249528, -120.8435)
))
```

You can execute the query at the link below.
https://console.developers.google.com/project/280742519599/apiui/api/fusiontables/method/fusiontables.query.sql

Answer (score 0):

FusionTables doesn't support the intersection of 2 polygons. There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=395) that has been marked "WontFix"